# Can't Find a Usable init.tcl in the Following Directories - Python Tkinter Matplotlib App

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tcl, auto-py-to-exe

I am having an issue with my Python Tkinter(Customtkinter) Matplotlib App, in my pc after I execute the app with auto-py-to-exe (adding the customtkinter directory) its working fine, tried to run it on 4 other PCs but after RUN it crashes due to the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 339, in <module>
File "customtkinter\windows\ctk_tk.py", line 38, in __init__
tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, **pop_from_dict_by_set(kwargs, self._valid_tk_constructor_arguments))
File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2263, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
{C:\Users\krist\OneDrive\??????? ????\test\main\tcl} {C:/Users/krist/OneDrive/??????? ????/test/main/tcl8.6} {C:/Use
rs/krist/OneDrive/Pa6omen nnom/test/lib/tcl18.6} {C:/Users/krist/OneDrive/Pa6omen nnom/test/lib/tcl8.6} {C:/Users/krist/0
neDrive/Pa6omex naom/lib/tcl8.6} {C:/Users/krist/OneDrive/Pa6omen nnom/test/library} {C:/Users/krist/OneDrive/Pa6omeH na
om/library} {C:/Users/krist/OneDrive/Pa6omex naom/tcl8.6.9/library} C:/Users/krist/OneDrive/tcl8.6.9/library
This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
[8016] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

[image: image of the error]

The file that causes the error is in the tcl directory of the app.

Source code:
https://github.com/DianVK/amplitude_modulated_signals/blob/7345db2d174d8e5f8e3df5484819411a95a65cc3/main.py

the files in the executed app:

[image]

[image]

Please suggest me how to deal with the issue. The computers that I want to run the program on dont have any of Python / Tkinter / Matplotlib installed, but even when I tried to install Python, the error is still appearing.

Tried all the currently available solution for such an issue. None of them worked.

Comment: Please share your code/errors as text in the question and not as images

Comment: Interesting. *Something* has garbled a directory name there. Don't know if that matters. Tcl and Tk internally use the Wide version of Windows system calls to avoid many of these sorts of problems...

Comment: Still cant find the cause of the issue.